# pip install error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1 after

Tags: python, python-3.x, boost, pip, miniconda

I am trying to install a python package called job_stream [https://wwoods.github.io/job_stream/#installation](https://stackoverflow.com), on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
I installed minidconda3, then installed boost using "conda install boost," from inside my virtualenv. I am trying to do the next step which is "pip install job_stream," however, I am getting an error `"command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1`
Below is the whole message I am getting

```
Building wheels for collected packages: job_stream
  Building wheel for job_stream (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp: In constructor ‘boost::mpi::environment::environment(bool)’:
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp:74:3: error: ‘MPI_Errhandler_set’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘MPI_Errhandler_free’?
         74 |   MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
            |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |   MPI_Errhandler_free
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp: In constructor ‘boost::mpi::environment::environment(boost::mpi::threading::level, bool)’:
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp:89:3: error: ‘MPI_Errhandler_set’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘MPI_Errhandler_free’?
         89 |   MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
            |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |   MPI_Errhandler_free
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp: In constructor ‘boost::mpi::environment::environment(int&, char**&, bool)’:
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp:102:3: error: ‘MPI_Errhandler_set’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘MPI_Errhandler_free’?
        102 |   MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
            |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |   MPI_Errhandler_free
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp: In constructor ‘boost::mpi::environment::environment(int&, char**&, boost::mpi::threading::level, bool)’:
      boost-mpi-1.61/src/environment.cpp:118:3: error: ‘MPI_Errhandler_set’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘MPI_Errhandler_free’?
        118 |   MPI_Errhandler_set(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERRORS_RETURN);
            |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |   MPI_Errhandler_free
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for job_stream
  Running setup.py clean for job_stream
Failed to build job_stream
ERROR: Could not build wheels for job_stream, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Does anybody know why I am getting this and how to solve it?

I have tried adding the lib paths in my `.bashrc`

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/include/boost/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/include/boost/
```

I also tried

```
conda install -y gcc
```

But that failed with `PackagesNotFoundError`

But still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have python3-dev installed?

With you being on Ubuntu 22.04 it should be running Python 3.10. So to install the python3-dev you will need to run
`sudo apt install python3.10-dev`.

Comment: I am actually running Python 3.11, and I already have python3.10-dev installed.

Comment: I had seen other comments to install python3-dev and so had done that, but am running python3.10 -- so running sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev fixed this for me. Thanks!